# dynamic memory allocation in c?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

```
#include <stdio.h>
.
.
.
// Dynamic Array
int **tab=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
   tab[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    }
// Array = 0
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    tab[i][0]=0;
    tab[i][1]=0;
}
.
.
.
```

The program crashes just after the Array = 0 comment.
PLease help my assignment is due.

NOTES:
n is given by the user and can be any int.

Comment: What is the value of `n`?

Comment: If `n > 2` this will crash when you try to dereference a non-existent pointer in `tab[2]`

Comment: @Dancrumb could you, please, care to elaborate on this? Thanks.

Comment: [Do not cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: You only allocate the first two entries in your `tab` array in your first loop. When you try to access the third one in your second loop, you'll be trying to dereference a NULL pointer, hence a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're only allocating memory for the first 2 pointers of tab and not n elements. Then if n is greater than 2 you're trying to dereference pointers that could point to anything. To fix this just change the 2 in the first for loop to n.

```
for(i=0; i < n; i++)
{
    tab[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
}
```